# Data collection board

Tags: adc, data

Im currently working with the [DC718C](https://www.analog.com/en/resources/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/dc718c.html#eb-documentation) data collection board, and I'm using PScope to collect the data and MATLAB for further processing.

I want to know if it's possible to collect more than 131072 samples (which is the maximum amount of samples I can extract from PScope), by either using PScope or another alternative.

The datasheet says: "The Linear Technology supplied PScope evaluation software automatically detects the DC718 and in select cases can also detect the ADC demonstration circuit under evaluation. This system provides for fast and easy performance evaluation of high speed ADCs by collecting up to 128k word samples".

Is the limitation due to the memory data buffer or simply the PScope software?

Comment: This would be a better question for analog devices, but seeing as the eval board lists enough memory for 128k samples and no more, good chance that's all it can hold.

Comment: You can use MATLAB to interface directly with the DC718C board and collect data beyond the limits imposed by PScope.

Comment: Hello @liaifat85, Do you have any suggestions on how this can be done?. or can you recommend any notes/video that tells how it can be done

Comment: I could not find any note which directly talks about interfacing  DC718C with MATLAB. But as far as I know,  DC718C supports I2C communication. Here is a general guideline about  how to interface an I2C device with Matlab. https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/ref/matlabshared.i2c.device.html

Comment: @liaifat85. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it